# SQL query how to divide values from two columns from the same table in different condition

Tags: sql

Supposed I have some sample data in `table_name_a` as below:

```
    code    val    remark   date
   -----------------------------------
1   00001    500    111      20191107
2   00001   1000    222      20191107
3   00002    200    111      20191108
4   00002    400    222      20191108
```

When I input code '00001' and date '20191107', I need the output as below:

```
        code    val    
        -------------
    1   00001   0.5
```

This SQL query must be wrong query, because I got wrong result as below:

```
         code    val
        --------------
0        00001   Null
1        00001   Null
2        00001   Null
3        00001   Null
4        00002   Null
5        00002   Null
6        00003   Null
7        00004   Null
8        00005   Null
```

```
SELECT 
    code, val
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         code, date,
         CASE WHEN t.remark = '111' THEN t.value ELSE 0 END /
         CASE WHEN t.remark = '222' THEN t.value ELSE 0 END AS val
     FROM 
         table_name_a t
     WHERE 
         code IN ('%(code)s')
         AND date IN ('%(input_date) s')) AS t1
```

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: Why is it not simply `SELECT code, val/100 FROM t WHERE code = '0001' and remark = 111 and date = '20191107'` ? Your requirements aren't very clear, please expand..

Comment: Storing dates as a string will eventually bite you in the rear end. Change it while you still can. Also ever putting `x / CASE WHEN ... ELSE 0 END` in a query will likely one day lead to a division by 0 error. Do null instead of 0, so that the division produces null

Comment: in your internal t1 table your select 3 columns: code, date and val, but in the external one you miss the date column. This is a first error I see.

Comment: you attempt to divide by zero, mysql is kind enough to return NULL for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like below

```
select code, 
sum(case when remark=111 then val else 0 end)/sum(case when remark=222 then val else 0 end) as val
from table where code= '00001' and date= '20191107'
group by code
```

Comment: I think the table only has one item of remark=111, do I  still need `sum()` ?

Comment: In that case no need

Comment: @FIRE . . . On the other hand, you need something and the `SUM()` does no harm.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with something like that:

```
select t1.code, t1.date, t1.val / t2.val from table_name_a t1 
    join table_name_a t2 on t1.code = t1.code and t1.remark = '111' and t2.remark = '222'
where t1.code in (...) and t1.date in (...)
```